# facing following error in programme

Tags: java, swing

```
jTable1 = new javax.swing.JTable();
String columns[]={"ID","Subject","Author","Type"};
jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(this.arr,columns));

jTable1.setName("jTable1"); // NOI18N

jTable1.addAncestorListener(new javax.swing.event.AncestorListener() {
    public void ancestorMoved(javax.swing.event.AncestorEvent evt) {
    }
    public void ancestorAdded(javax.swing.event.AncestorEvent evt) {
        jTable1AncestorAdded(evt);
    }
    public void ancestorRemoved(javax.swing.event.AncestorEvent evt) {
    }
});

jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTable1);
```

in this code everything is fine but it is not printing any thing in jtable. even i have checked that array does not contain null value and it contain values in it. no syntax error. can any one tell me what can be the reason for this code not to display data in table?

Comment: We need to see your data array (`this.arr`).

Comment: i have checked that array that array is perfectly fine and printed exact values but things happening are beyond my thinking...

Comment: We can hardly help you if you can't show more code. The snippet you show doesn't have any problem when you limit the focus to what is there, which means the problem is outside this code.

Comment: why are you asking when you are so convinced that everything's fine? Somewhere, your wiring isn't correct. You either have to find it yourself or show a short, runnable example so we can help you to spot it

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure what the error you get is.

But by adding a stub array like this:

```
static String[][] arr = {
    { "some Id1", "some subject1", "some author1", "some type1" },
    { "some Id2", "some subject2", "some author2", "some type2" } };
```

Your program looks like this:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.AncestorEvent;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

class Test {
    static String[][] arr = {
        { "some Id1", "some subject1", "some author1", "some type1" },
        { "some Id2", "some subject2", "some author2", "some type2" } };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JTable jTable1 = new javax.swing.JTable();
        String columns[]={"ID","Subject","Author","Type"};
        jTable1.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(arr,columns));
        jTable1.setName("jTable1"); // NOI18N

        jTable1.addAncestorListener(new javax.swing.event.AncestorListener() {
            public void ancestorMoved(AncestorEvent evt) {}
            public void ancestorAdded(AncestorEvent evt) {
                //jTable1AncestorAdded(evt);
            }
            public void ancestorRemoved(AncestorEvent evt) {}
        });

        JScrollPane jScrollPane1 = new JScrollPane();
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTable1);

        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setContentPane(jScrollPane1);
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: i need not a static array but the data which i want to display is fetched from database

Comment: i need not a static array but the data which i want to display is fetched from database

Comment: If you update the array, you need to do [fireTableChanged](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html#fireTableChanged%28javax.swing.event.TableModelEvent%29) etc. (Also, note that if you do `new arr[...][...]` the table model won't know about the reference to the new arary. You'll have to *edit* the existing array reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the DefaultTableModel with a table model that prints out the problem. Using the decorator pattern

```
public class DebuggingTableModel implements TableModel {
  private final TableModel tableModel;

  public DebuggingTableModel(TableModel m) {
    tableModel = m;
  }

  @Override
  public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
     Object result = tableModel.getValueAt(rowIndex,columnIndex);
     System.out.println("getValueAt"+rowIndex+","+columnIndex+","+result);
     return result;
  }
  //Do something similar for all other methods in TableModel
}
```

Now replace

```
jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(this.arr,columns));
```

with

```
jTable1.setModel(new DebuggingTableModel(
    new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(this.arr,columns)));
```

And the problem will print itself.